# Access nested structures without moving

Tags: nested, rust

I've got these structs:

```
#[derive(Debug, RustcDecodable)]
struct Config {
    ssl: Option<SslConfig>,
}

#[derive(Debug, RustcDecodable)]
struct SslConfig {
    key: Option<String>,
    cert: Option<String>,
}
```

They get filled from a `toml` file. This works perfectly fine. Since I got an `Option<T>` in it I either have to call `unwrap()` or do a `match`.

But if I want to do the following:

```
let cfg: Config = read_config(); // Reads a File, parses it and returns the Config-Struct
let keypath = cfg.ssl.unwrap().key.unwrap();
let certpath = cfg.ssl.unwrap().cert.unwrap();
```

It won't work because `cfg.ssl` gets moved to `keypath`. But why does it get moved? I call `unwrap()` on `ssl` to get the key (and `unwrap()` it to). So the result of `key.unwrap()` should get moved?

Or am I missing a point? Whats the best way to make these structs accessible like this (or in a other neat way)? I tried to implement `#[derive(Debug, RustcDecodable, Copy, Clone)]` but this won't work because I have to implement `Copy` to `String` as well. Then I have to implement `Copy` to `Vec<u8>` and so on. There must be a more convenient solution?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

What is the definition of `Option::unwrap`? [From the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap):

```
fn unwrap(self) -> T
```

it consumes its input (`cfg.ssl` here).

This is not what you want, you instead want to go from `Option<T>` to `&T`, which will start by consuming `&self` (by reference, not value)... or you want to `clone` the `Option` before calling `unwrap`.

Cloning is rarely the solution... the alternative here is [`as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref):

```
fn as_ref(&self) -> Option<&T>
```

And therefore you can write:

```
let keypath /*: &String*/ = cfg.ssl.as_ref().unwrap().key.as_ref().unwrap();
                                    ^~~~~~~               ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: `cfg.ssl.as_ref().map(|ssl| &ssl.key).unwrap()` is shorter... I'm not sure if it's a *better* thing to write here, though.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt: Looks a bit complicated... though of course the issue here is `unwrapping` nilly willy.

Comment: Arguably you could avoid the first unwrap with `as_ref().and_then()` instead of `unwrap`, but at *some* point you have to either assert the Option is Some or reasonably handle the error.

Comment: @Jsor Thanks for pointing that out: my code snippet is wrong, of course. It should say `and_then` instead of `map`...

Comment: @Jsor If we assume that some code before `as_ref().and_then()` already checks for correctness, what difference would it make to use `.and_then()`. Or the other way: What would be improved by it?

Comment: It took me a few days, after I read this and many other explanations, to get to the gist of it: accessing a nested fields is OK. But during it, move out of field can occur. In this case, because `unwrap()` and `map()` consume `self`; in my case, even moving of `Option<&SomeType>` was still a move, because it moved `Option<>`.

Answer (score 11):

> So the result of `key.unwrap()` should get moved?

Yes, but not only that. The key insight here is, that a variable get's moved into of `unwrap()`. Let's look at [the function signature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap):

```
fn unwrap(self) -> T { ... }
```

It takes `self`, so the object is *moved into the function*. But this applies to `ssl.unwrap()`, too!

So when writing:

```
cfg.ssl.unwrap().key.unwrap();
```

You first move `cfg.ssl` into `unwrap()`, then you access one field of the result and move that field into `unwrap()` again. So yes, `cfg.ssl` is moved. In order to solve this, you can save the temporary result of the first `unwrap()` call, like so:

```
let ssl = cfg.ssl.unwrap();
let keypath = ssl.key.unwrap();
let certpath = ssl.cert.unwrap();
```

Or you can look at the [`as_ref()` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref), if you don't want to move (which is probably the case).

Comment: Thanks for you explanation. Helped me a lot to understand the problem I had!